# Include preamble statements depending on compiler

Tags: compiling, conditionals

I am trying different compilers like pdfLatex, luaLatex, latex to try differences in compiling things like pgfplots. But when i shange the compiler I also need to change the preamble. How can i do something like this pseudo-code:

```
if compiler == lualatex
  \usepackage{luaotfload}
  ...
elseif compiler == pdflatex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  ...
fi
```

to avoid repetitively commenting and uncommenting code?

Comment: Packages `ifluatex` and `ifpdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages `ifluatex` provide for `\ifluatex` and `ifpdf` for `\ifpdf` statements.

Use it `\ifluatex ... \else ... \fi`

(`\ifpdf` as well)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}


\ifluatex
  \usepackage{luaotfload}
\else
\ifpdf 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\typeout{PDF only}
\fi
\fi

\begin{document}

\ifluatex
Yeah, it's lualatex
\else
\ifpdf
Hooray, it's pdflatex
\fi
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\ifpdf` only checks whether the output is PDF or DVI, so it's true when `lualatex` is used.

Comment: There is also the `ifxetex`package.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that did the job! And thanks egreg, that explains why the suggested structure worked and two separate statements gaver errors when using Lua.